# Enabling munin-agent throught Windows Server Firewall

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, monitoring, munin

I installed munin-node on some servers and so far they seem to be working pretty nicely. However since I was asked to install the munin-agent on a Windows Server 2012 R2 I'm having some problems.

Well, from the beginning.

I downloaded the munin agent (https://sourceforge.net/projects/munin-nodewin32/) and executed on the server. I added the windows server addres on the /etc/munin/munin.conf , as you can see.

```
[serverwindows.domain.local]
     address 192.168.1.15
     use_node_name yes
```

And restarted the munin-node service on my monitoring server.

I added the inbound rules on windows firewall to allow the port 4949 used by munin. However even when the graphs appear (image 1) on the munin web interface, it does not receive updates. Then I tried to connect the munin-master on the port that it uses using nc -vvv 192.168.1.15 4949 but the connection always end in a timeout(see above the image).

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDSrs.png)

```
[root@monitor ~]# nc -vvvvvvv 192.168.1.15 4949
Ncat: Version 6.40 ( http://nmap.org/ncat )
libnsock nsi_new2(): nsi_new (IOD #1)
libnsock msevent_new(): msevent_new (IOD #1) (EID #8)
libnsock nsock_connect_tcp(): TCP connection requested to 192.168.1.15:4949 (IOD #1) EID 8
libnsock nsp_add_event(): NSE #8: Adding event
libnsock nsock_loop(): nsock_loop() started (no timeout). 1 events pending
libnsock select_loop(): wait for events
libnsock process_event(): Processing event 8
libnsock process_event(): NSE #8: Sending event
libnsock nsock_trace_handler_callback(): Callback: CONNECT TIMEOUT for EID 8 [192.168.1.15:4949]
Ncat: Connection timed out.
```

After all that, I know that somehow windows firewall is still blocking the port 4949, since when I turned the firewall off for testing it started to update the graphs normally. I don't know if I'm missing something or just configured the inbound rules wrongly. I would really apreciate some thoughts or help.

PS: Sorry about the grammar, I'm not used to write in english, but now I'm tight spot not knowing what should I do.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind after some reading on the git files I ended up actually compiling the nsi file on the installer folder after correcting the path on NSIS Firewall and executing on my windows server 2012 R2 I finally managed to connect without any problems. Now I only need to discover why the graphs aren't updating and showning -nan values.